# Angular an Independent Block of CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a factory I call that returns some HTML. I would like to display this HTML in a section of my app, but I don't want its CSS to affect the site's, nor do I want the site's to affect it. It needs to be an iframe more or less but I feel like there's a better way to do it in Angular.

I essentially have something like this (Angular 1.2)

```
var promise = myFactory.getHtml();
getTemplate.then(function(data) {
    $scope.mine.html = $sce.trustAsHtml(data.data);
});
```

I can display this HTML no problem, but it looks terrible inside of my app. How can I make it independent?

Comment: Can't you just wrap that section in a div and give it it's own class. Then pass that class custom CSS? That way the custom css for that class doesn't override anything in your app, but you still get the specific styling that you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Select your element (say using an id selector) and use the following rule to reset all its properites

```
all: initial;
```

see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/all

and then apply the specific properties for your div. For example

**CSS**

```
div {
    color: red;
    background-color: blue;
}
#a {
    all: initial;
    color: blue;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="a">asdf</div>
```

The fact that it is an angular template need not come into the picture.